# Can I apply polyurethane to a new table?

Tags: polyurethane

I'm buying a new kitchen table and dining room table, and I'm trying to keep them from getting scratched from regular use. Can I apply several coats of polyurethane to a brand new table top to make it scratch-proof?  Or will that ruin the finish?

Comment: Depends on the finish it has now. Photos are always good because it makes it more likely you will get an answer that works for your specific situation.

Comment: Most catalyzed finishes will be harder than polyurethane, so you'd be lowering the scratch protection. The traditional trivet and placemat combination would be more effective.

Comment: Polyurethane is not, itself, scratch-proof, so, no, that will not make it scratch-proof.

Answer (score 2):

(See my above comment) Unfinished or stained wood is best for a poly finish. Have you considered getting a clear glass top protector for your tables? 1/4" glass is pretty cheap and you can get it cut to size with a beveled edge. Affix it to table with clear adhesive pads--very cheap and easy to use. Going with glass will be MUCH LESS work and will last forever (pretty much).

[image: glass tabletop protector]  [image: tt pro]

Comment: And it's but-tugly.   The proper way to protect wood furniture IMHO is the same as for wood floors:  treat them with proper respect and care.